# Android broadcasting over 3g

Tags: android, tcp, udp, broadcast, 3g

I'm in the early stages of writing an app that will need to broadcast data to several other devices.

My first thought was using an UDP broadcast, however according to both 
http://code.google.com/p/boxeeremote/wiki/AndroidUDP and
[Android 3G UDP Broadcast](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/7363530/android-3g-udp-broadcast)
he UDP will not be able to push through the NAT when on the mobile network 
(which is essential for my app).

I know that i could either use a server to broadcast however i'd rather avoid generating to much traffic on my home server.

The last alternative that i can think of is having several tcp/ip connections and looping through all connected clients and sending the broadcast. But since I'm counting on having at least 30 listeners I believe this will be to expensive.

I do not have any broadcast associated code yet, that's why I haven't posted any;)

Is there a way to break through the NAT? Will the phone be able to handle 30 simultaneous tcp/ip connections? Or should i look into some other method of broadcasting?

Any hint would be greatly appreciated!

Kind regards
Johan Risch

:::::::::::::::::::::::::ADDED::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::
I will be sending strings of length 10-20 characters once every 30-360 seconds 
(will be controllable by the user) containing geo points in string format. The order in which the data will be sent is not important, that's why I thought of udp first.

I've set up my server so that when a user logs in he/she updates my database with his/her current ip.

Preferably i'd like it to work globally, but as long as it would work within the mobile networks in the same country.

That's about all the relevant information i can think of, hope this clears some things up!
:::::::::::::::::::::::::/ADDED:::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::::

Comment: It would help if you explained exactly 'what' you will be broadcasting, how often, locations of the other devices etc. Somebody might be able to suggest alternatives if you post a bit more detail.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The NAT doesn't pass UDP through because UDP has no destination address, so technically UDP has to be sent to *all* subnetworks of the network. When the network is your home LAN, it's no big deal, but when the network is your ISP or university backbone or cellular provider, the UDP could be replicated to hundreds of thousands of subnets.  That's a packet storm that will degrade network performance for everyone, and it's massive overkill for your particular app since you really only want to talk to a small number of clients.

This problem has been solved many times already. Instant Messaging clients have a similar situation as yours: want to do direct P2P messaging when possible, through firewalls. How do they do it? The original NAT traversal / firewall traversal solution was to set up a message relay server.  All clients talk to the server, and the server echos messages from one client to the others as appropriate.  It works with NATs and firewalls because the client initiates the outgoing connection to the server.

If the clients are able to establish a peer to peer connection, then the relay server can just give the clients each other's IP addresses and stop relaying messages.

UPNP is a protocol that enables clients to request a firewall to open a port for incoming traffic. BitTorrent clients use UPNP to enable clients to connect P2P for file sharing. Clients find each other via the torrent server. Most home LAN firewall routers support UPNP now, but it seems doubtful to me that a cellular network provider would provide UPNP support for over the air connections.

Another (remote) possibility is multicast TCP/IP, but as I recall this is really optimized for "push" content flowing from the server to clients rather than client-originated peer to peer.

Your best bet is to take a look at the open source IM clients out there, particularly ones with Android implementations, and see how they're doing IM. [Jabber](http://jabber.org) is one that comes to mind, I'm sure there are others. You could even use an IM system's messaging API as your data transport layer and more or less stay out of the wire level details completely.